# how to correctly check for scroll end?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using the [scroll method](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html?highlight=scroll#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.scroll) to get a large number of events in batches. I do not know how to properely stop the scrolling.

What I am doing right now (it works) is to check for a `TransportError` which signals a failed scroll attempt:

```
scanResp= es.search(
    index="nessus_all",
    doc_type="marker",
    body={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
    search_type="scan",
    scroll="10m"
)
scrollId= scanResp['_scroll_id']
while True:
    try:
        response = es.scroll(scroll_id=scrollId, scroll= "10m")
        # process results
    except Exception as e:
        log.debug("ended scroll: {e}".format(e=e))
        break
# we are done with the search
```

This generates an error in `/var/log/elasticsearch/security.log`:

```
[2015-02-16 09:36:07,110][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [eu4] [2791] Failed to execute query phase
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [eu5][inet[/10.81.147.186:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/scan/scroll]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.SearchContextMissingException: No search context found for id [2791]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.findContext(SearchService.java:502)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeScan(SearchService.java:236)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchScanScrollTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:939)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchScanScrollTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:930)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and generally does not seem the right way to go?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Elasticsearch's Scroll documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) (as of version 5.1):

> Each call to the scroll API returns the next batch of results until there are no more results left to return, ie the hits array is empty.

So, I believe that the best method would be to check for `len(response['hits']['hits'])`.

A more concrete example:

```
response = es.search(
    index='index_name',
    body=<your query here>,
    scroll='10m'
)
scroll_id = response['_scroll_id']

while len(response['hits']['hits']):
    response = es.scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id, scroll='10m')
    # process results
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking more closely at `.scroll()` I came up with

```
scanResp= es.search(
    index="nessus_all",
    doc_type="marker",
    body={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
    search_type="scan",
    scroll="10m"
)
scrollId= scanResp['_scroll_id']
totalhits = scanResp['hits']['total']

while totalhits > 0:
    response = es.scroll(scroll_id=scrollId, scroll= "10m")
    # process results
    totalhits -= len(response['hits']['hits'])

# we are done with the search
```

Comment: Why do they return a scrollId if there is nothing left to scroll ... ? Maybe in case more docs just arrive in the mean time ??